# Proving Trig. Identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

$\cot x=\sin x \sin(\pi/2 -x) + \cos^2x \cot x$

I'm having difficulty with figuring out how to prove trigonometric identities.  I know that in order to do these you need to use the trig ratios reciprocal, quotient  identities and compound angle formulas.  If someone could guide me through these kind of questions.  That would be really appreciated!

Comment: @Ash did you not just ask this exact same question?

Comment: Yes, similarily but this time I would like someone to go through each step with me rather than simply posting the answers

Comment: @Ash The question structures don't differ. If you were not completely satisfied with the answer, don't accept it. Ask additional questions there in the comments instead of trying to figure it out by posting a separate question that is almost identical to the other one. At the very least you should point out what precisely you want that the answer did not provide. Either way this question is inevitably going to be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Oh.. well would it be possible if the first version is closed since I find this one is helping me better?

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) + \cos^2(x)\cot(x) = \sin(x)\cos(x) + \cos^2(x)\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ and now we want to find a common denominator to add the fractions so we get $\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} + \frac{\cos^2(x)\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \cot(x)$

Comment: So this is all influencing the LHS (left-hand side of the equation?

Comment: all of this is manipulating the RHS and then the final step is showing that it is equal to the LHS